# Error combining an element and an array in Swift Array Extension - Works in Xcode but not in LeetCode

Tags: swift, closures

I've been trying to implement a function inside an Array extension in Swift that returns all the permutations of an array. When I run this code in Xcode, it seems to work just fine. However, when I tried the same code in LeetCode, I encountered the following error:

```
Line 10: Char 24: error: cannot convert value of type 'Array<Element>' to closure result type 'Element'
[tar]  +  ac
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```swift
extension Array  {
    func permute() -> [[ Element ]] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [[]] }

        return (0...count-1).flatMap { i in
            var dup = self
            let tar = dup.remove(at: i)

            return dup.permute().map { ac in
                [tar]  +  ac
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line causing the issue is [tar] + ac. I'm puzzled because of the inconsistency in behavior between Xcode and LeetCode. How can I resolve this so that it works on both platforms?

What I tried:
I implemented an Array extension in Swift to generate all permutations of an array. The approach I took was to recursively break down the problem, removing each element and getting permutations of the rest. Then I would combine the removed element with these permutations.

Expected Outcome:
I expected my permute() function to return all possible permutations of the input array. When tested in Xcode, it provided the correct results, with each permutation being a separate array.

Actual Result:
When I transferred the code to LeetCode and attempted to run it, I encountered a compile-time error on the line [tar] + ac. The error stated:

This was surprising as there was no such issue in Xcode.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you included the full signature for each closure. You missed to include the error message in the second to last paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Leetcode is using an older version of Swift, probably Swift 5.6, since the [error is reproducible on Swiftfiddle as well](https://swiftfiddle.com/kwnjucdp3jd5xesd7bjixctdvu) using the 5.6 compiler.

You simply need to type annotate the return values of the closures and your code will compile fine using Swift 5.6 as well. See [this](https://swiftfiddle.com/mp6mcffvyrb4rp2q3axh3g2oca) Swiftfiddle playground. The reason you don't need to do this in Swift 5.7 and later is [SE-0326](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0326-extending-multi-statement-closure-inference.md), which was implemented in Swift 5.7 and enabled multi-statement closure return type inference.

```
extension Array  {
    func permute() -> [[ Element ]] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [[]] }

        return (0...count-1).flatMap { i -> [[Element]] in
            var dup = self
            let tar = dup.remove(at: i)

            return dup.permute().map { ac -> [Element] in
                [tar]  +  ac
            }
        }
    }
}
```